# How to update the time without closing the UI in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, time

I want to create a system that has a time in/time out feature.

I tried this code as a trial before including the the feature to my system:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Time extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

     Date now = new Date();
     private JLabel time;
     private JButton getTime;
     private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

public Time()
{

  setLayout(null);
  setSize(500,300);


  JLabel time = new JLabel("00:00:00");
  time.setSize(100,100);
  time.setLocation(40,40);

  JButton getTime = new JButton("GET TIME");
  getTime.addActionListener(this);
  getTime.setSize(90,30);
  getTime.setLocation(90,70);

  Container pane = getContentPane();

  pane.add(time);
  pane.add(getTime);

  setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getActionCommand() == "GET TIME")
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time "+dateFormatter.format(now),       
"Time.",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Time();
}
}
```

It gets the current time, but it still gives the same time when I click again the button. It only changes when I close the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Canned answer:**

Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if ("bar".equals(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

---

**Uncanned answer:**

So in other words, change this:

```
if (e.getActionCommand() == "GET TIME")
```

to this:

```
if ("GET TIME".equals(e.getActionCommand())
```

or better still, use String constants.

Also, you'll want to avoid using null layout in your Swing GUI's as you'll find out that that is the hard way to lay things out. Much easier and more robust is to use layout managers.

**Edit**
You need to get the time from within your actionPerformed method. In other words, `now` should be created in the actionPerformed method before calling the JOptionPane.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getActionCommand() == "GET TIME")
    {
        now = new Date();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time "+dateFormatter.format(now),
```

Comment: Although in this case, the 2 strings are string literal and should be `==`... So the problem is probably something else.

Comment: How about the problem in updating the time?

Comment: both ways doesn't change anything. It still gets the same time

Comment: @kdot: again, please see edit. If this doesn't work for you, please show us your latest code attempt as an edit to your question (not as a comment).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the same time because you've declared the Date variable as a global variable and initialized it globally as well. You should change the implementation of your `actionPerformed` as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Date now = new Date(); //Create a new instance of date
    if ("GET TIME".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Time " + dateFormatter.format(now), "Time.",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }           
}
```